# How to dynamically resize 3 divs on window.resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div style="min-width:1024px;max-width:82%;margin:0 auto;overflow:auto">
    <div style="height:344px;width:100%;float:left;margin-top:72px"></div>
    <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
        <div id="left" class="radius" style="height:700px;width:220px;background:#fff;float:left"></div>
        <div id="middle" class="radius" style="width:760px;background:#fff;float:left;margin:0px 18px;">
            <div style="height:700px;width:100%;float:left"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="right" class="radius" style="height:700px;width:280px;background:#fff;float:left"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and script:

```
function scalling() {
    var a = $(window).width();
    if (a < '1300') {
        var def = a * 82 / 100,
            l = 22000 * def / 10,
            m = 76000 * def / 10,
            p = 28000 * def / 10;
        $('#left').css('width', l);
        $('#middle').css('width', m);
        $('#right').css('width', p);
    } else {
        $('#left').css('width', '220px');
        $('#middle').css('width', '760px');
        $('#right').css('width', '280px');
    }
}

scalling();
$(window).resize(function () {
    scalling();
});
```

It works but add size to divs in oder way when window is scaling to be biger divs are smaler and when window is smaller the divs are bigger

Sorry for my bad anglish

Comment: Just as a general comment. There is a lot of in-line styles and JavaScript that changes styles in that code. This is not going to be maintainable at all. Why not let CSS do what it does best and let it worry about the display of elements using media-queries for example and let JavaScript worry about functional code? Some resources on that: [**MDN on Media Queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and [**CSS Tricks on Media Queries**](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use this CSS statement:

```
@media ( min-width :1300px){
    selector{
        width: constant-value;
    }
}

@media ( max-width :1300px){
    selector{
        width: percent-value;
    }
}
```